# Rendering justified text - I cannot get the words to align by baseline

Tags: text-rendering, imagesharp

I am using the ImageSharp library to render multiple lines of text, and I want each line to be justified. I want the spacing to be dynamically calculated to ensure the first character is left aligned and the final character is right aligned.

I wrote some code to do this. This code divides the string up into words, sums up the total word widths, subtracts this total from the available width to determine the available space, and then assigns this space to each word break. It then renders each word separately.

The problem is the vertical alignment. Words can have different vertical heights depending upon the letters they have. The word 'in' has a different height to the word 'Mojo'. Here is how it's currently rendering. You can see vertically small words like 'over' are not aligned properly.

[image]

How can I render two words separately so each word's vertical **baseline** is aligned?

Here is my current code:

```
public static IPathCollection RenderJustifiedText(
    string text,
    PointF startPos,
    float width,
    Font font
)
{
    var textOptions = new TextOptions(font);
    var wordsAndWidths = text.Split(' ')
        .Select(
            w =>
            new
            {
                Word = w,
                Width = TextMeasurer.MeasureBounds(w, textOptions).Width,
            }
        ).ToArray();
    var spaceRemaining = width - wordsAndWidths.Select(ww => ww.Width).Sum();
    var eachSpace = spaceRemaining / (wordsAndWidths.Length - 1);
    float xPos = startPos.X;
    List<IPathCollection> allPaths = new();
    foreach (var w in wordsAndWidths)
    {
        var textPath = new PathBuilder()
            .AddLine(
                new PointF(
                    xPos,
                    startPos.Y
                ),
                new PointF(
                    xPos + w.Width,
                    startPos.Y
                )
            ).Build();
        allPaths.Add(
            TextBuilder.GenerateGlyphs(
                w.Word,
                textPath,
                textOptions
            )
        );
        xPos += w.Width + eachSpace;
    }
    return new PathCollection(allPaths.SelectMany(pathCollection => pathCollection));
}
```

Comment: You'd have to measure and offset the origin of each section. However, it's probably best to see if we can justify text at the layout level. Add a discussion to the ideas channel in the Fonts repository.

Comment: @JamesSouth Can you explain what the :"origin" represents in this context?

Comment: origin is the TextOptions.Origin. You'd have to offset each section by the diff between the lead and ascender of each glyph. It's horribly complicated so I wouldn't bother. We can add justified text layout to the library so that it happens as part of the layout operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v1.0.0-beta18 there is a new `TextJustification` enum in `TextOptions`. The options and implementation supporting the
[CSS Text Module Level 3 text-justify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify) property. This allows you to easily justify text of mixed font sizes.

I've added some example output below.

##### Horizontal

`TextJustification.None`

[image: none]

`TextJustification.InterWord`

[image: inter-word]

`TextJustification.InterCharacter`

[image: inter-char]

##### Vertical

`TextJustification.None`

[image: v-none]

`TextJustification.InterWord`

[image: v-inter-word]

`TextJustification.InterCharacter`

[image: v-inter-char]